# can not find product information stored in index table

Tags: magento-1.9, product, index, table

what is table names where product infromation stored in database.Like `product_name,description,short_description,sku` because I can not find index tablr where product all information stored in table. please anyone tell me table name ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this, may be it can help you.

https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/list-of-product-tables-in-magento/

Comment: I am talking about product indexing structure not EAV structure.

Comment: Finally I found table name from database .table name is catalog_product_flat_1